# How to check if a database entry exists using HQL description

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

The JpaRepository allows for executing some SQL queries without having to specify these specifically. For example, it is possible to execute the following method: `myRepository.existsById(id)`.

I would like to execute this method, but instead of checking for the existence of the id, I would like to check for a different property, which I call employeeId. I am aware that I will have to specify this query; this is what I have tried:

```
@Query("SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t WHERE t.employeeId = ?1")
Integer existsByEmployeeId(Long id);
```

I am calling this method just before executing a DELETE query:

```
  public Long deleteEntryByEmployeeId(Long id) {
    if (myRepository.existsByEmployeeId(id) == 1) {
      myRepository.deleteEntryByEmployeeId(id);
      return id;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

This doesn't really work as expected though, as I am returned the error:

```
Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "myRepository.existsByEmployeeId(java.lang.Long)" is null
```

I understand that `myRepository.existsByEmployeeId(id)` returns null. This seems to be the case if there is no entry in myTable for the specified id. Anyways, I am looking for a smooth solution to this problem. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches.

1. You want to stick with declarative `@Query` annotation.

```java
@Query("SELECT CASE WHEN count(t) = 1 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END FROM MyTable t WHERE t.employeeId = ?1")
Integer existsByEmployeeId(Long id);
```

2. It's OK to implement custom functionality.

```java
public interface CustomEmployeeRepository {
    boolean existsByEmployeeId(Long id);
}


@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
class CustomEmployeeRepository implements CustomEmployeeRepository {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;    

    @Override
    boolean existsByEmployeeId(Long id) {
        List list = em.createQuery("SELECT 1 FROM MyTable t WHERE t.employeeId = :id")
          .setParameter("id", id)
          .getResultList();
        return list.size() == 1;
    }
}

// inject EmployeeRepository and call existsByEmployeeId as usual
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, CustomEmployeeRepository {
    
}
```